# Not able to Insert Record in Junction Table in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm new to Yii2. I've three tables project, amenity and a junction table project_amenity, and here is the code:

**Project Model:**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Project extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getAmenities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Amenity::className(), ['id' => 'amenity_id'])->viaTable('project_amenity', ['project_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'city'], 'required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**Amenity Model:**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Amenity extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getProjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::className(), ['id' => 'project_id'])->viaTable('project_amenity', ['amenity_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

**ProjectController**:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Project;
use app\models\Amenity;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $project = new Project;
        $amenities = ArrayHelper::map(Amenity::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');

        if ($project->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $project->save()) {
            return $this->render(['confirm', 'id' => $project->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'project' => $project, 'amenities' => $amenities
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Incomplete **create** view:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><?= $form->field($project, 'name'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><?= $form->field($project, 'city'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**ProjectAmenity** Junction Model

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class ProjectAmenity extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'project_amenity';
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['project_id', 'amenity_id'], 'required']
        ];
    }
}
?>
```

I'am able to display the relational data but not able to insert. Please suggest how to display the amenity checkboxes on create view and and how to **insert** the data in **project** and **project_amenity** table from the create view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add amenities property to your project model:

```
public $amenities;
```

Add a [checkboxlist](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkboxList()-detail) to your view:

```
<?= $form->field($project, 'amenities')->checkboxList($amenities) ?>
```

Create junction model if not already exists.

Loop through input in create action after save:

```
if ($project->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $project->save()) {
    // checkboxlist fills amenities property with corresponding keys
    foreach($project->amenities as $amenity_key) {
        $project_amenity = new ProjectAmenity([
            'project_id' => $project->id,
            'amenity_id' => $amenity_key
        ]);
        $project_amenity->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your instruction but error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". Please see the junction model code, updated above.

Comment: Thanks after defining rules for amenities property it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?=   $form->field($project, 'amenities')->inline()->checkBoxList( 
        ArrayHelper::map(Amenity ::find()->all(), 'name', 'name'),
        ['style'=>'width:500px']
        )
      ?>
```